# CodeBlocks plugin which replaces constans in source

Tags: c++, plugins, codeblocks

I'm looking for a plugin to CodeBlocks which is able to replace constants in source:

Assuming consts::CONST1 == "test1" and consts::CONST2 == "test2":

```
...
#include "consts.hpp"

int main() 
{    
    std::string s = "foo";    
    function1(consts::CONST1 + s + consts::CONST2);    
    return 0; 
}
```

I'd like to select some part of code and switch between something like this "test1" + "foot" + "test2" and oryginal look. Is there any plugin/tool like this?

Comment: Replacing a variable with its initialiser won't give equivalent code unless both have the same type (and often not even then). In particular, `"test1" + "foot" + "test2"` won't even compile.

Comment: You don't understand, I don't want to replace those constans by it's constant literal, just to know what's hiding under each one (source code will stay unchanged). I need such feature because it will be easier for me to analize code which contains a lot of constanst literal defined in other source files.